How to protect my SSR Quasar app from Cross site request forgery (CSRF)?
I am making a Server Side Rendered Application with Quasar framework, and I want to implement authentication.

Should I store JSON Web tokens in cookies?
What would be the most secure cookie?
How should I protect from Cross site request forgery (CSRF) attacks?
Should I use preFetch feature to authorise user?
How to avoid cross-request state pollution with Pinia?
Would it be safer to store JWTs in local storage and render user-only content only in client side?
When JWT is unsafe?

